# jQuery Steps with 5 steps

Tags: jquery

I can not acomplish "jQuery Steps wizard plugin(http://www.jquery-steps.com/)" works with 5 teps, i can show five steps but next button does not go to the five step when i press it stays in the four step.

I have changed "stepwizard.css":

```
.wizard > .steps > ul > li
{
    width: 25%;
}
```

to:

```
.wizard > .steps > ul > li
{
    width: 20%;
}
```

I don't know if I have to change the JavaScript, has someone worked with more than 4 steps?

Configuration:

```
var settings = {
    /* Appearance */
    headerTag: "h1",
    bodyTag: "div",
    contentContainerTag: "div",
    actionContainerTag: "div",
    stepsContainerTag: "div",
    cssClass: "wizard",
    stepsOrientation: $.fn.steps.stepsOrientation.horizontal,

    /* Templates */
    titleTemplate: '<span class="number">#index#.</span> #title#',
    loadingTemplate: '<span class="spinner"></span> #text#',

    /* Behaviour */
    autoFocus: false,
    enableAllSteps: true,
    enableKeyNavigation: true,
    enablePagination: true,
    suppressPaginationOnFocus: true,
    enableContentCache: true,
    enableCancelButton: false,
    enableFinishButton: true,
    preloadContent: false,
    showFinishButtonAlways: false,
    forceMoveForward: false,
    saveState: false,
    startIndex: 0,

    /* Transition Effects */
    transitionEffect: $.fn.steps.transitionEffect.none,
    transitionEffectSpeed: 200,
```

[image]

Comment: Could you show me the page?

Comment: @Maxim Jin i already updated